# grep - print all lines containing 'cat' as the second word

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Ok so considering i have a file containing the following text:

```
lknsglkn cat lknrhlkn lsrhkn
cat lknerylnk lknaselk cat
awiooiyt lkndrhlk dhlknl
blabla cat cat bla bla
```

I need to use grep to print only the lines containing 'cat' as the second word on the line, namely lines 1 and 4. I've tried multiple `grep -e 'regex' <file>` commands but can't seem to get the right one. I don't know how to match the N'th word of a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may work for you?

```
grep -E '^\w+\s+cat\s' file
```

if the first "word" can contain some non-word characters, e.g. `"#, (,[.."`, you could also try:

```
grep -E '^\S+\s+cat\s' file
```

with your example input:

```
kent$  echo "lknsglkn cat lknrhlkn lsrhkn
cat lknerylnk lknaselk cat
awiooiyt lkndrhlk dhlknl
blabla cat cat bla bla"|grep -E '^\S+\s+cat\s'
lknsglkn cat lknrhlkn lsrhkn
blabla cat cat bla bla
```

Comment: Indeed it does ! But just to make sure i'm getting this right: you put in -E for extended regular exp, the ^ is for line start w is for matching the word, + for matching 0 or more times, and \s+cat\s is the string cat ?

Comment: @axesdenied `+` means `1..n`, not `0..n`, `*` means `0..n`

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes a word?

```
grep '^[a-z][a-z]*  *cat '
```

This will work if there is at least a blank after `cat`.  If that's not guaranteed, then:

```
grep -E '^[a-z]+ +cat( |$)'
```

which looks for `cat` followed by a blank or end of line.

If you want a more extensive definition of 'first word' (upper case, digits, punctuation), change the character class.  If you want to allow for blanks or tabs, there are changes that can be made.  If you can have leading blanks, add '`*`' at the caret.  Variations as required.

These variations will work with any version of `grep` that supports the `-E` option.  POSIX does not mandate notations such as `\S` to mean 'non-white-space', though GNU `grep` does support that as an extension. The `grep -E` version will work with regular `egrep` if `grep -E` does not work but `egrep` exists (don't use the `-E` option with `egrep`).

Comment: I've upvoted since this also works and is good for the learning experience :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
grep -e '^\S\+\scat\s'
```

The line should start with a non-whitespace of length at least 1, followed by a whitespace and the word "cat" followed by a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Will be slower, but perhaps more readable:

```
awk '$2 == "cat"' file
```